# Keep getting the Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres when I try to connect to docker container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, typeorm

I keep getting this error through my typeORM DataSource connection when I'm trying to connect to my dockerized postgres database.

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
  node_app:
    build: ./node
    container_name: node
    environment:
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=4000
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: sh -c "npm start"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/home/node/app:cached
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: job_matching
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
    networks:
      - postgres-db-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
```

**app.ts**:

```js
const dataSource = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.PGHOST || 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'job_matching',
  entities: ['src/models/**/*.ts'],
});
```

**Error in docker**:

```
Error during Data Source initialization Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgres
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres'
}
```

**What I have tried so far**:

1. connect to the postgresql through the terminal with `psql -h localhost --port 5432 -U postgres` => worked !
2. check that the node app is started depends on postgres service healthiness
3. check that I have only one postgres service running on port 5432 with `lsof -i :5432` => `com.docke 27212 sbagherzadeh  329u  IPv6 0x81fea2c6d7e20ca9      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)`
4. check that  I request the container name instead of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
5. try to use a .env file instead of the env variables directly from the docker compose file.

I'm running out of solutions if someone can help please :) !

Comment: `postgres` is on the `postgres-db-network` but `nod_app` is not.  so they're not networked together.

Comment: @erik258, you're damn right. Do you want to add an answer instead of a comment to allow me to mark it as the right solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`postgres` is on the `postgres-db-network` but `node_app` is not. so they're not networked together.  So they can't talk.  Thus, docker does not expose their container names to each other as resolvable hostnames.